# attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference app driver

Tags: android, location, uber-api

**my error >**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)'
> on a null object reference

```
driverLocationRef.removeEventListener(driverLocationRefListener);
driveHasEndedRef.removeEventListener(driveHasEndedRefListener);
```

**my void >**

```
if (driverFoundID != null) {
            DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID).child("customerRequest");
            driverRef.removeValue();
            driverFoundID = null;

        }


        driverFound = false;
        radius = 1;
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerRequest");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.removeLocation(userId);


        if (pickupMarker != null) {
            pickupMarker.remove();
        }
        if (mDriverMarker != null) {
            mDriverMarker.remove();
        }


        mRequest.setText("VOCÊ CANCELOU O CHAMADO, PEÇA NOVAMENTE!");

        mDriverInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mDriverName.setText("");
        mDriverPhone.setText("");
        mDriverCar.setText("Destination: --");
        mDriverProfileImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_default_user);
    }
```

Comment: Please add some details to let the community help you troubleshoot: add some more details like the stacktrace, the conditions when this happens etc...

Comment: Either `driverLocationRef` is null or `driveHasEndedRef` is null. Now as to why they are null, we need more code for the first code section and a full error log.

Comment: this happens when i search for a driver and there is none online, then when i press the cancel button the app crash

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Simone Avogadro, you need to provide more information so one can troubleshoot.

Regardless of that, according to error message from logcat,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference
```

it says you are trying to remove listener from null object, check when you have added the listener on database reference, make sure your object reference is not null.

Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

```
07-31 04:44:44.736 7958-7958/com.simcoder.matheus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.simcoder.matheus, PID: 7958
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.simcoder.matheus.CustomerMapActivity.endRide(CustomerMapActivity.java:391)
        at com.simcoder.matheus.CustomerMapActivity.access$100(CustomerMapActivity.java:61)
        at com.simcoder.matheus.CustomerMapActivity$2.onClick(CustomerMapActivity.java:139)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: full error log, this happens if i have a calling driver action on, and this app crash on the cancel search driver action.